# show an array() into table

Tags: php

My primary task was, to validate that the backlinks of my website is there or not which is validated through a some.txt file. I have done it but now the problem is, I want the urls in table format.

My script is this

```
$needle = $_GET['utext'];
$file   = $_GET['ufile'];
$source = file_get_contents($file);
$new    = explode("\n",$source);

foreach ($new as $check)
{
  $a = file_get_contents(trim($check));
  if (strpos($a,$needle))
  {
    $found[] = $check;
  }
  else
  {
    $notfound[] = $check;
  }
}

echo "Matches that were found: \n ".implode("\n",$found)."\n";
echo "Matches that were not found \n". implode("\n",$notfound);
```

Comment: What's inside the txt file?

Comment: I write my own script but it is not showing here. I write a script which takes a some.txt file and a text field where we write our URL. Then that url is searched on each and every link present in that some.txt file.

Comment: What are you stuck with? What do you mean by "table format" exactly?

Comment: What have you tried? Change the `echo` statements to echo a table, and you're done...

Comment: inside the txt file there are links. and my url has backlink to every link present in .txt file.

Comment: use `foreach` to loop through elements and output a table row for each one.

Comment: $needle = $_GET['utext'];$file = _GET['ufile'];
$source = file_get_contents($file);
$new = explode("\n",$source);
foreach ($new as $check){
$a = file_get_contents(trim($check));
if (strpos($a,$needle)){
$found[] = $check;
}else{ $notfound[] = $check;} }
echo "Matches that were found: \n".implode("\n",$found)."\n";echo "Matches that were not found \n". implode("\n",$notfound);?>This is my script.

Comment: Honey: Maybe also have a look at http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues for your use of strpos (because you better use === or !== to compare)